# Why isn't the `else` arm executed in this Bash script (for loop through an array)?

Tags: bash, quoting, bash-array

The following code is meant to look for subdirectories in `~/Downloads`. I run it with `. ./script.sh`. It will find them even when the user submits an incomplete name.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo -e "\nGive me the name of a nonexitent directory and I will look for it in ~/Downloads?\n"

read word

TOGOs=("$(find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$word*" -type d -execdir echo {} + | sed 's;./;/home/smith/Downloads/;g')"
"")
for togo in ${TOGOs[@]}
do
  if [[ $togo != "" ]]; then
    echo $togo
    export togo && cd $togo && return 0
  else
    echo "Haven't found it in ~/Downloads ." && cd ~/Downloads #This line does not work
  fi
done
```

The `if` part works as expected - when I give it a name/part of the name of a subdirectory of `~/Downloads/`, but the `else` part of the block never gets executed when I give it a nonexisting directory. I can get the `else` part executed when I get rid of the loop, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo -e "\nGive me the name of a nonexitent directory and I will look for it in ~/Downloads?\n"

read word
TOGO=$(find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$word*" -type d -execdir echo {} + | sed 's;./;/home/smith/Downloads/;g')

if [[ $TOGO != "" ]]; then
  echo $TOGO
  export TOGO 
  cd $TOGO && return 0
else

  echo "Haven't found it in ~/Downloads." && cd ~/Downloads
fi
```

Why is it so the `else` arm gets executed when I get rid of the loop? How might I get
my code executed while preserving the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${TOGOs[@]}` means to take the elements of the array, break them into separate words at whitespace (assuming the default `IFS`), and interpret each word as a glob pattern. It's the same as `$var` for a scalar variable, except that it lists all the elements in turn.

If there's an empty element in the array, the splitting step turns it into a list of 0 words, so it's effectively removed.

[As always: use double quotes around variable and command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) unless you know that you need to leave them out. To list the elements of an array, the correct syntax is `"${TOGOs[@]}"`. The array access “wins” over the double quotes: each element of the array is placed into a separate word.

Using the correct syntax for array listing won't help you, though, because the way you construct the array doesn't make sense. You're putting the whole output of `find` into a single array element. You can't parse the output of `find` that way: there's no way to distinguish between a newline that's part of a file name and a newline that `find` uses to distinguish file names.

Instead of parsing the output of `find`, do the processing in bash, or use `find -exec …`. Bash has recursive globbing (enabled by [`shopt -s globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)) if you need it, but since you're using `find -maxdepth 1` you actually don't need it, and `find` isn't really doing anything useful.

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
TOGOs=(~/Downloads/*$word*/)
if [[ ${#TOGOs[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Haven't found it in ~/Downloads."
fi
for togo in "${TOGOs[@]}"; do
  …
done
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works fine. Simply placing double quotes around `${TOGOs[@]}` also solved the issue in my code. Would you decode `#` in `if [[ ${#TOGOs[@]} -eq 0 ]]`?  P.S. `""` is meant to be the second element of the array `TOGOs`.

Comment: @JohnSmith `${#TOGOs[@]}` is the length of the array. This checks whether the array is empty.